# A question on Riemann integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

Consider the function $f(x)=x$ when $x$ is rational and $f(x)=-x$ when $x$ is irrational. I want to show that the function is not Riemann integrable on any interval $[a,b]$. Clearly the function is only continuous at $x=0$. So if zero is not an element of $[a,b]$ the function is discontinuous every where. So the function has infinitely many discontinuities. Is telling this sufficient to prove that this is not Riemann integrable?

Comment: Yes. Let $D$ be the set of discontinuities. Then, $\text{Msr}(D) = 1$; that is the discontinuities have measure one. So, $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a theorem that a function is Riemann integrable if and only if its points of discontinuity form a measure zero set; in particular, this means that the function is not Riemann integrable if it is discontinuous everywhere.  (Infinitely many discontinuities is not enough; the function $f(\frac{m}{n}) = \frac{1}{n}$ when $\frac{m}{n}$ is rational and in lowest terms, and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise, is discontinuous on all rational numbers and is Riemann integrable.)

However, this theorem may be too advanced for your context; my guess is that you want to show that on some subinterval, the upper sums for any partition are bounded below by a positive number and the lower sums bounded above by a negative number.  Use the fact that in any interval, there are both rational and irrational numbers.

Comment: Any upper sum is positive and any lower sum is negative right?

Comment: That is correct, though not quite enough (because what if they both go to zero from different directions as the partition gets finer?).  Suppose that you have an interval $[a,b]$ where $a>0$ (the same idea works if $b<0$, and any interval has a subinterval of one of these types).  Show that the lower sums are smaller than $-a(b-a)$ and the upper sums larger than $a(b-a)$.